# Windows Server 2008 ( 32 and 64 bit) with AMP stack

Tags: windows-server-2008

I just wonder how well does AMP stack ( Apache, MySQL and PHP) runs on Windows Server 2008 ( both 32 bit and 64 bit version)?

Anyone has any experience on it?

**Note: I don't expect any problem, but still it is useful to pool other's experience.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack itself is fine (There are some unrelated issues between IIS and PHP, but as you use Apache that won't be the case), but keep in mind that some PHP Applications may have dependencies on Linux - I have seen more than one Application that had hardcoded /tmp as it's temporary file path, or that tried to use the exec/system commands to execute Linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and PHP work fine on Windows 2003 x86 so I'd expect no problems on 2k8 (assuming User Access Control doesn't do something unexpected). In older versions of PHP the ISAPI version used to crash, but the current version seems fine. You can have fun deciding where exactly php.ini has to live, but experiment usually quickly sorts it.

I have no experience of Apache on Windows .

JR